# React TypeScript 16.8 How to make useEffect() async

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await, react-hooks

Why can't `useEffect()` use async-await?

```
const Home: React.FC = () => {
    
    useEffect(async () => {
        console.log(await ecc.randomKey())
    }, [])
    
    return (
    ...
```

The error I get is

> Argument of type '() => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.

> Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => void | undefined)'.

> Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type '() => void | undefined'.

> Type 'Promise' provides no match for the signature '(): void | undefined'.ts(2345)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Declaring the effect as async function is not recommended.
But you can call async functions within the effect like following:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const genRandomKey = async () => {
    console.log(await ecc.randomKey())
  };

  genRandomKey();
}, []);
```

More here: [React Hooks Fetch Data](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/)

Comment: Be careful doing this.... async callbacks after await could return after a react component has been dismounted and if you touch any component state in that scenario react will crash and throw some nasty errors.

Anytime you are doing async things in a useEffect etc you should be checking if the component has unmounted before touching state.

Comment: I'm getting an IDE warning saying Promise returned from asyncMethod is ignored. Is this mechanism really safe?

Answer (score 40):

You can use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (asynchronous anonymous function which executes itself) like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    // Some synchronous code.

    (async () => {
        await doSomethingAsync();
    })();

    return () => {
        // Component unmount code.
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: For those who don't know what it's called, it is IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) and here's the MDN link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`use-async-effect`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-async-effect) package which provides a `useAsyncEffect` hook:

```js
useAsyncEffect(async () => {
  await doSomethingAsync();
});
```