# I have a problem with the async function in typescript

Tags: typescript

Please, can anyone help me? JavaScript works fine, but with the type of these errors ...
I don't know what to do anymore!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQLmi.png)

```
const Dasboard: React.FC = () => {

const [repositories, setRepositories] = useState([]);

 useEffect(async (props: any) =>  {
      const response = await fetch('https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/');
        const data = await response.json();
        setRepositories(data);

    }),[];



return(
<>


  <Container>

  {repositories.map(repo => (
    <li key={repo}>

    </li>
  ))

  }

  </Container>


  </>

);
}


export default Dasboard;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React TypeScript 16.8 How to make useEffect() async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57238928/react-typescript-16-8-how-to-make-useeffect-async)

Answer (score 1):

With `useEffect`, you're either supposed to return a teardown function, or nothing at all. But since you're using an async function you're returning a promise instead, so typescript is pointing out your misuse of useEffect.

Instead, make the async function inside the function that you pass to useEffect, then call it:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/');
    const data = await response.json();
    setRepositories(data);
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

If you prefer, you can do it as an immediately invoked function expression:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/');
    const data = await response.json();
    setRepositories(data);
  })();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback passed to useEffect cannot be an `async` function.

To do something `async` within a `useEffect`, you can take this approach:

```
useEffect(() =>  {
   const getData = async () => {
     const response = await fetch('https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/');
     const data = await response.json();
     setRepositories(data);
   }

   getData()
},[]);
```

[This article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data) provides more details.